# How to insert new column using numpy and conditionally add values to it

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array *img(640, 400, 3)* It basically contains a pixel array of an image loaded via OpenCV library. Some of the pixels are zero *[0, 0, 0]* and other are non-zero *[r, g, b]* values

How do I -

1. insert another column to make the shape of it *(640, 400, 4)* to add the alpha values, so that the pixels become *[r, g, b, a]*, where *a* is the alpha value
2. In this new column, the *alpha* value needs to be set based on a condition: if *[r, g, b] == 0* then *alpha == 0* else *alpha == 255*. i.e, my new pixels should be either *[0, 0, 0, 0]* or *[r, g, b, 255]*

How do I do this in numpy itself, I don't want to use OpenCV to re-read the image to generate the alpha values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rgb = np.random.uniform(0, 255, (100, 100, 3)).astype("uint")
# example position with [0,0,0]
rgb[0, 0, :] = 0

# mask where condition is satisfied
msk = np.sum(rgb, axis=2)==0

# Prep the alpha layer
nrows, ncols, _ = rgb.shape
alpha = np.ones((nrows, ncols), dtype="uint") * 255

# Make positions that satisfy condition equal to 0
alpha[msk]= 0

# add extra alpha layer
rgba = np.dstack([rgb, alpha])
```